# Vimeo PRO Account - Categorizing Videos

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

So I am at my wits end here. Our company has paid for a "PRO" account which I assume stands for "Professional". The need we have is to upload and host videos with Vimeo. However, these videos should not be available to the world. Hence the need for our account, our entire account, to be in "Private" mode. But we still need to keep each client's videos grouped or categorized together for management purposes.

Unfortunately I have not been able to find any way to do this when a "PRO" account is in private mode. Per the documentation at (https://vimeo.com/help/faq/vimeo-membership/vimeo-pro#how-can-i-share-my-videos-if-im-in-private-mode) accounts which are in private mode cannot use Albums, Channels, or Groups regardless of how much they paid for membership. The documentation goes on to recommend using Portfolios, but there is no API integration for portfolios whatsoever.

So does anyone know of how to accomplish this "seemingly" simple task of taking say 3 clients and uploading 4 videos each, but yet have all the videos categorized or grouped by client? The only two ways I've come up with so far is to rename the videos a certain way before uploading and/or creating and maintaining a second, seperate database on my own which takes care of the sorting and management. I would rather not do either of these options though. I'd like to just use the API with the account that I paid for on Vimeo.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Vimeo's in beta API3 has portfolio support. You can request access via https://vimeo.com/help/contact
2. If your account is not in private mode, but all of your videos are marked "Hidden from Vimeo" then the videos will be private on Vimeo, available via an embed on your own website, and able to be added to albums.

I would recommend both choices, Switch to API3 and start marking your videos "Hide from Vimeo" instead of marking your whole account as private

Comment: Does 'Hide from Vimeo' mean that the video is not accessible with any (hidden) direct link to the video? http://danbeahm.blogspot.nl/2014/01/vimeo-hide-this-video-from-vimeocom.html This article suggests that it can be accessed. If you e.g. get the video-id from a private area where the video is embedded you can still share it with others?

Comment: Hide from Vimeo will (sometimes, unreliably, with no official support or assurance of it's continued existence) be accessible through that URL, but the other important privacy flag is "only embeddable on these domains". You can see an example of that url being successfully blocked here : http://player.vimeo.com/video/98664982